# Android Auto / GridItem / Showing custom Image?

Tags: android-auto

I'm currently creating an Android Auto Application, and for the Grid-View that is to be used, the user is able to store own images during runtime in the smartphone-view.

Now, when displaying these entries In Android Auto through the `GridItemBuilder` i'm trying to reuse the image, that has been stored by the user. `CarIconBuilder` offers the possibility to use `IconCompat`, which im trying to do. But running these lines of code:

```
 public Template onGetTemplate() {
    ...
    String fileName = carContext.getCacheDir() + "/state_img_" + state.optLong("id") + ".png";
    File imageFile = new File(fileName);

    if (imageFile.exists()){
       IconCompat icon = IconCompat.createWithContentUri(Uri.fromFile(imageFile));
       gib.setImage(new CarIcon.Builder(icon).build(), GridItem.IMAGE_TYPE_ICON);
    }else{
       //TODO: Handle No-Image-Case.
    }

    gib.setTitle(state.optString("name"));
    gib.setLoading(false);
    ...
}
```

returns the builder-exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported URI scheme for: Icon(typ=URI
> uri=file:///data/user/0/my.namespace.appname/cache/state_img_1698487391260.png)

The file is detected existing, and displaying it in the mobile-view through `ImageView` also works flawless. Not sure, where the issue is with Car-Icon-Builder here, any idea?

Answer (score 1):

After trying a bunch of different things, finally creating a bitmap first is working now:

```
if (imageFile.exists()){
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
    IconCompat icon = IconCompat.createWithBitmap(bmp);
    gib.setImage(new CarIcon.Builder(icon).build());
}else{
    //TODO: Handle No-Image-Case.
}
```